# How to feed multiple inputs of images (batch of images) in inference to a Nvidia TensorRT?

Tags: python, nvidia, tensorrt

### Environment

I use **tlt container version2** which support trt and pycuda:
tensorrt version : 7.0.0-1+cuda10.0
**GPU Type**: 1080 Ti

when I run inference for single image this part of code works perfectly:

```
np.copyto(inputs[0].host, img.ravel())
```

but when I run it for multiple images in a list (batch_size>1):

```
np.copyto(inputs[0].host, img_list.ravel())
```

it gives me an error.

Does trt model support multiple input of images in inference?
if it is then how to feed multiple images into inputs[0].host in inference part of tensorrt?

Answer (score 1):

So GPUs and their "capacity" to hold images are what defines how many images it can hold of a given size. There is something called GPU memory, in case of NVIDIA [A100](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/data-center/a100/)(which is the highest capacity GPU available currently with NVIDIA) its 40GB.
So it all ultimately boils down to your GPU's memory and has got nothing to do with TensorRT, TensorRT is just an SDK

Comment: Thanks Umang Sharma. Do you know how to feed mutiple images into inputs of tensorrt?